# Prove that if $R$ is real closed field, $f \in R[X]$, and $f(a)f(b) <0$ for some $a < b$ in $R$, then $f(r) = 0$ for some $a < r < b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Prove that if $R$ is real closed field, $f \in R[X]$, and $f(a)f(b) <0$ for some $a < b$ in $R$, then $f(r) = 0$ for some $a < r < b$.

Suppose that $f$ is a irreducible polynomial of degree 1 and $f(a)$ is negative. Then $f(b)$ must to be positive.. I don't know what more to do, any hint?

Comment: I am tempted to hit it with a hammer. The theory of real-closed fields is complete, so any two real-closed fields are elementarily equivalent. For polynomials of any fixed degree, the assertion is a sentence of the theory of real-closed fields, and is true in the reals (Intermediate Value Theorem), so it is true in any real-closed field.

Comment: Isn’t a real closed field, by definition, elementarily equivalent to $ \mathbb{R} $? Consequently, any first-order statement (in the first-order language of field theory) that is true of $ \mathbb{R} $ is true of $ R $, and conversely.

Comment: See Theorem 2.5 in Chapter XI (on real fields) of Lang's Algebra. It doesn't involve appeals to mathematical logic like the previous comments. Instead, earlier in that chapter Lang proves every odd-degree polynomial in $R[x]$ has a root, from which it follows by Galois theory that $R(i)$ is an algebraic closure of $R$, where $i^2 = -1$.  It follows that all irreducibles in $R[x]$ have degree $1$ or $2$, and see Lang for the rest of the argument addressing your question about the intermediate value theorem for $R[x]$.